# Why can't I adopt children?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-hearthfire

I have a child´s chest, a child´s bed, and light. I tried to adopt children from the orphanage but it doesn't work.

Comment: I want this question on the HNQ list so bad   ‎

Answer (score 6):

Adoption have requirements :

- Having a house with a child bedroom or a second room in a self-built house.
- Finishing the [Innocence Lost](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Innocence_Lost) quest

As you said, you have the bedroom.

Have you finished the Innocence Lost quest ?

Answer (score 4):

Since you've completed the house requirements, here are the other thing you need to do:

1. You need to complete Innocence Lost by going into the Arentino Residence and talk to Aventus. After it's complete, later go back and talk to the lady Constance. I know you're trying to adopt from the orphanage.

If you still can't adopt from the orphanage, you can adopt the other following children: Lucia from Whiterun, Blaise from Solitude, Sophie from Windhelm, and Alesan from Dawnstar.

If nothing works, download the Hearthfire Unoffical Path which fixes some things in the game depending on the DLC pack.

Comment: Wouldn't this be better as an edit to PapaStan's answer? You're not adding any more information towards the issue at hand (adopting **from the orphanage**; and only specifying the name of the NPC at the orphanage and where the quest starts), you're not actually providing **new** information

Comment: @Oak that's what people say, you could just answer with more info too. Edited with too much info isn't good. That's the purpose. I just provided new info too `You can also adopt Lucia from Whiterun, Blaise from Solitude, Sophie from Windhelm, and Alesan from Dawnstar.` You think that's not new?

Comment: Editing with good information is never an issue, as long as it stays true to the original question/answer. About the other children: It's new information, yet irrelevant to the question; The question is regarding adopting **from the orphanage**. Your question has two parts, one doesn't awnser the question (it's just good trivia with alternatives, which is okay) and the other is the same as a previously made answer

Comment: @Oak what if OP doesn't know about other adoption alternatives? This answer provides that little piece of extra information. Plus editing this into the previous answer will deviate from the posters original intent, making it a not so great idea.

Comment: @JustDoIt that's correct. If there's more info, put it in the answer. If you want to correct something and put a little info, that's ok.

Comment: @Oak that's just how it works. If you think I'm still wrong, let the high rep users see this.

Comment: What if the user has all of the requirements but still can't adopt from the orphanage? There is still another pathway through adopting, which is random orphans in cities. If doing so from the Orphanage doesn't work, then there has to be another way. You can't just expect it to be, "Oh, but even though it's that he still said Orphanage!"

Comment: Another example: "If you can't get this follower, try another follower." The Other Guy: "But the question is asking all for one person!"

Answer (score 0):

So all you have to do is head to rifton and kill the other caretaker, after that go to the western watchtower and press X (If you have an Xbox remote) This enables an elder dragon to fly by, follow the dragon in flight until you reach theives guild hiding place and ask for the guild members to help you defeat the dragon (It will cost you) and head back to the orphanage, (it should be on fire because of the dragon) and you should be able to get an orphan for free.